# How can I make a dataframe filtering the dataframe by the max value of a column?

Tags: python

I have this dataframe which is grouped by the name of an object and I want to make a new dataframe filtered by the max value of `column1` but keeping the corresponded value of the other columns.

```
                               Date    Column1  Column2 Column3
    NAME             Id             
 Object1            1548    2011-04-01  16926.0 1233.0  0.0
                    1548    2017-08-01  2340.0  224.0   21.0
                    1548    2017-07-01  2463.0  230.0   26.0
 Object2            1549    2017-06-01  2451.0  247.0   27.0
                    1549    2017-04-01  2347.0  240.0   21.0
```

This is an example of the result I want:

```
                               Date    Column1  Column2 Column3
    NAME             Id             
 Object1            1548    2011-04-01  16926.0 1233.0  0.0
 Object2            1549    2017-06-01  2451.0  247.0   27.0
```

Comment: so you want first 2 rows?

Comment: No, I want to filter the dataframe by the max value only of column1 to have a result as the example one.

Comment: Thanks @Epsi95, but is not returning the result I want.

Comment: Thanks to Tomerikoo for edit my question. Sorry, I am new learning Python.

Answer (score 0):

use `groupby`

```py
df.groupby(['NAME']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Column1'], ascending=False).head(1))
```

```
Object1 0   Object1 1548    2011-04-01  16926.0 1233.0  0.0
Object2 3   Object2 1549    2017-06-01  2451.0  247.0   27.0
```

Comment: You nailed it bro, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dataframe as df

First of all reset the index.
df = df.reset_index()

You can use max() to get maximum values of column1.

```py
df1 = df.groupby(["NAME"])['Column1'].max() #returns max values of column1 of 2 names
```

Then you can put all the series in one list

```py
a=[]
for n in list(df1):
  a.append(df[df['Column1'] == n].iloc[0,])

df2= pd.DataFrame(a)
display(df2)
```